# OpenStreetMapを Windows/Mac(ローカル環境) に構築する方法/手順を教えてほしい

Tags: openstreetmap

ローカル環境(Windows or Mac)で、OpenStreetMapを使いたいために、サーバーを構築しようとしています。
公式などのガイドもみましたが、対象OSがUbuntuのため、参考にしづらい状況です。

最終的に行いたいことは、
　ローカル環境(Windows or Mac)で動作させるアプリケーション上に、
　OpenStreetMapの地図画像を表示する
という機能です。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: その後、以下の様なサイトを発見しました。

http://learnosm.org/jp/
日本語版ということもあり、こちらも参照してみようとおもいます。
http://learnosm.org/jp/osm-data/setting-up-postgresql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

データをポスグレに突っ込んで地図タイルを生成するまでの手順で終わっていますが、下記のリンクが参考になりませんか？

OpenStreetMap (OSM) Install on Windows – Part I
http://softwaresimian.com/2012/12/02/openstreetmap-osm-install-on-windows-part-i-the-database/

OpenStreetMap (OSM) Install on Windows – Part II
http://softwaresimian.com/2013/02/20/openstreetmap-osm-install-on-windows-part-ii-generate-tiles/