# GMap.NETでosmファイルを読み込むには？

Tags: openstreetmap

GMap.NETをネットワークのつながっていないローカル環境で使用したいと考えています。
事前にOpenStreetMapのosmファイルをダウンロードしておき、そのファイルを使用したいのですが、
GMap.NETでosmファイル読み込みを調べてみましたが、見つかりませんでした。
osmファイルを直接読む方法、osmファイルを何らかの方法で、gmdbに変換する方法等、
わかる方がいらっしゃれば、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

この辺の記事に、キャッシュデータをコピーして使う方法が記載されています。
いずれも古い記事ですので変わっている可能性もありますが、試してみてください。

[GMap.NET + C# + postgreSQL without Internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30033256/9014308)
[GMap .net offline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32711953/9014308)

以下のようなデモプログラム等を動かすと、キャッシュデータがローカルに出来ているそうです。

https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/tree/master/Demo.WindowsPresentation  
https://github.com/williamwdu/GMap.NETChacher

キャッシュデータはデフォルトで以下の位置にあるそうです。
直上の `en` は、設定等で変わっているかもしれません。
`USERNAME`はログインしているユーザー用のフォルダ名です。

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\GMap.NET\TileDBv5\en\Data.gmdb

他に明示的にキャッシュの場所を指定できるようです。

> use `gmap.CacheLocation = @"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\";` to specify the cache location.

SQLiteのファイルで、デフォルトや明示的に指定した、同じ位置にファイルをコピーするだけで動作するとのこと。

---

そして、こちらの記事に自作プログラムでキャッシュデータ(のみ)を使う方法などが書かれています。
[GMap.NET explicit load cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40847505/9014308)

---

その他
`OSM`と他のフォーマットとの`Import/Export`対応表(ツールも記載)が以下になります。
[Converting map data between formats](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Converting_map_data_between_formats)

GMap.NETでGoogleのKMLフォーマットの対応中？というQ&Aおよび記事がこちら。
ただし本家開発元は未対応。
[How to import/export kml and display in gmap.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49830759/9014308)
[gmap.net|C#|DXF|KML||robot|mission](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UO5m_xuUoHE)

上で紹介されていたTutorialサイト(参考になるかは不明)
[GMap.NET | Independent Software](http://www.independent-software.com/category/gmap.html)

---

**追記：可能かどうか不明ですが、アイデアとして。**

PCの中にOpenStreetMapサーバーのコピーを構築し、GMap.NETの参照先をそこに切り替えるとかが考えられます。

古いですが、この記事が使えるかも。
[OpenStreet map server installation on windows](http://openstreetmapserverwindows.blogspot.com/2015/11/osmopenstreetmap-tile-server.html)
[Local OSM server on windows](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/13125/local-osm-server-on-windows)
[How to serve OSM mapnik tiles on Windows with Apache for leafLet.js](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/54208/how-to-serve-osm-mapnik-tiles-on-windows-with-apache-for-leafletjs)
[Are there any precanned OSM server setups for Windows that contain the database, data loader and anything else](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/37982/are-there-any-precanned-osm-server-setups-for-windows-that-contain-the-database-data-loader-and-anything-else)
[OpenStreetMapを Windows/Mac(ローカル環境) に構築する方法/手順を教えてほしい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/4948/26370)

参考にUbuntuで独自に立てた記事があります。
[OpenStreetMapサーバを自作する(Install OpenStreetMap on AWS EC2/Ubuntu14.04)](https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/install-openstreetmap-on-ec2-ubuntu14_04/#alternative-plan-setup-own-tile-server)
[OpenStreetMap のタイルサーバー立ててみました](https://blog.mori-soft.com/entry/2017/12/28/104556)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ただ教えていただいた方法は指定した緯度、経度の周辺を読み込んでキャッシュする方法だと思います。
この方法ですと日本全国、アメリカ全土などのデータすべてをキャッシュするのはかなり大変だと思います。
今回、日本全国＆アメリカ全土の地図がオフラインで必要なため、事前にosmファイルをダウンロードして読み込ませたいと思い、質問しました。